# Capture.captureAudio() not working on Android

Tags: codenameone

I am making a very basic android app to conduct voice recording. However, Capture.captureAudio() did not include the needed android permission and no dialog was triggered. On the device, I checked also the permissions and no permission on audio recording is included.

Below is the code snippet.

```
start.addActionListener(e -> {
            String audioFile = Capture.captureAudio();
            if(audioFile != null) {
                String filePath = recordingsDir + "rec";
                try{
                    Util.copy(fs.openInputStream(audioFile), fs.openOutputStream(filePath));
                }catch(Exception er)
                {
                    textarea.setText(er.getMessage());
                    Log.e(er);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.p("AUdio file is null");
            }
            
        });
```

Comment: Are you sure the permission wasn't added to the manifest? I can see the code that triggers that and it's still active. I also see the permission dialog [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/AndroidImplementation.java#L8297C32-L8297C32). Can you run this with logcat and look at the logs to see if there's an exception?